# What consequences does it have, if I use `Any` as a type parameter constraint in general?

Tags: kotlin

I can use an unconstrained type paramter:

```
interface State<V>
```

or I can use a constrained type parameter:

```
interface State<V: Any>
```

This seems to be the same, because ["In Kotlin, everything is an object [...]"](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/basic-types.html). But this may be deceptive. What consequences does it have, if I favor the second instead of the first?

Comment: You have to write more code for the same effect?

Answer (score 1):

Please be aware the default upper bound is not `Any`, but `Any?`. There is no difference if we write `interface State<V>` or `interface State<V : Any?>` - this is the same thing.

However, `interface State<V : Any>` is different, it constrains `T` to be not nullable type:

```kotlin
interface State<V : Any>

class StringState : State<String> // ok
class NullableStringState : State<String?> // compile error
```

Both above classes compile fine if we don't specify the upper bound or we set it to `Any?`.

Comment: Is this the only consequence? Or are there additional consequences, which affect the compatibility to Java?

Comment: @ceving I'm not 100% sure and I don't have any official sources to support this claim. However,  I don't see a reason why setting something to a default value would be any different than leaving it default. Also, for using Kotlin code from Java, actually all these cases: `T`, `T : Any` and `T : Any?` produce the same JVM bytecode. This is because Java doesn't understand not nullable types and can't support them fully.